# Loop through tab delineated file in bash script

Tags: bash

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
        DB=$(echo $line | cut -f1)
        USER=$(echo $line | cut -f2)
        PASS=$(echo $line | cut -f3)
        echo DB=$DB USER=$USER PASS=$PASS
done < users.txt
```

And a sample of the input file:

```
drupal_1    drupal1 tmmjXSWL
drupal_2    drupal2 FHiJSYHM
drupal_3    drupal3 b7bFNj06
drupal_4    drupal4 0AaV62EL
```

And output from the script:

```
DB=drupal_1 drupal1 tmmjXSWL USER=drupal_1 drupal1 tmmjXSWL PASS=drupal_1 drupal1 tmmjXSWL
DB=drupal_2 drupal2 FHiJSYHM USER=drupal_2 drupal2 FHiJSYHM PASS=drupal_2 drupal2 FHiJSYHM
DB=drupal_3 drupal3 b7bFNj06 USER=drupal_3 drupal3 b7bFNj06 PASS=drupal_3 drupal3 b7bFNj06
```

For some reason, each variable is set to the whole line.  When I use `echo users.txt | cut -f1` at the command line, it returns the token just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
$ awk '{print "DB="$1"\tUSER="$2"\tPASS="$3}' users.txt
DB=drupal_1 USER=drupal1    PASS=tmmjXSWL
DB=drupal_2 USER=drupal2    PASS=FHiJSYHM
DB=drupal_3 USER=drupal3    PASS=b7bFNj06
DB=drupal_4 USER=drupal4    PASS=0AaV62EL
```

I can't tell if you have a problem to solve, or are wondering about a more theoretical issue.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I'm trying to write a script to create 40+ Drupal installations on a server for a class I'm teaching.  I have scripts to setup the DBs and files, this is a piece of the script that will put it all together.

The problem with my code was that the $line turned tabs into spaces as it parsed.  `$(echo $line | cut -d" " -f1)` also works.

Comment: fails for me if any of the fields contain spaces

Answer (score 25):

The problem is in the command `echo $line`. Since there are no quotes around `$line`, the shell performs word splitting on it, then interprets each word as a globbing pattern. Try it out with

```
a='*.txt foo'
ls $a
```

In your case, the tabs separate words, which then become separate arguments to `echo`. The `echo` command prints its arguments separated by a space. So `cut` ends up receiving space-delimited fields instead of tab-delimited fields.

**Always put double quotes around variable substitutions `$foo` and command substitutions `$(foo)`** (unless you understand why you need to leave them out and why it's ok to do so). `echo "$line"` would work here, but it's a complicated way of doing what you propose.

Keeping your approach of parsing in the shell, you can make the `read` command parse the input into fields.

```
while read DB USER PASS; do
  echo "DB=$DB USER=$USER PASS=$PASS"
done <users.txt
```

`read` splits fields separated by characters in the value of the `IFS` variable, which consists of a space and a tab (plus a newline, which can't occur inside a line) by default. To split only at tabs, set `IFS` to a single tab first. Note that leading and trailing tabs are ignored and consecutive tabs count as a single one.

`read` treats `\` as a special character: a backslash followed by a newline are ignored; `\\` becomes a single backslash. If you want to avoid this behavior, pass the `-r` option.

Comment: +1. To set IFS to a tab char in bash: `IFS=$'\t'`